# Can you reconfigure advertising packet during advertising BLE on ESP32

Tags: esp32, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to make a simple environmental sensing module on the ESP32 with ESP-IDF. I want to use BLE with gap only. I'm thinking of sending all the received data with the Advertising packets but since the sensor inputs are going to change periodically I'll have to send new data once in a while over the gap protocol. My question is do I have to stop advertising whenever I want to re-configure the advertisement data, or can I just do it in another thread (separate than the thread running BT)?

Sorry if my question is confusing, I'll try to clarify any points I messed up at explaining as more people answer : )

Comment: You do not need to have a thread dedicated to BLE advertisements. Just start advertising and go do something else. When you need to, change the data to advertise.